# how to pass suspend function as parameter to another function? Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, syntax, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I want to send suspending function as a parameter, but it shows " Modifier 'suspend' is not applicable to 'value parameter" . how to do it?

```
fun MyModel.onBG(suspend bar: () -> Unit) {
  launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        bar()
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The lambda's `suspend` modifier should be placed after the colon character, not before it. Example:

```kotlin
fun MyModel.onBG(bar: suspend () -> Unit) {
  launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      bar()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22870266)

Comment: Thx your very much, you help me to make code more clear!