# Kotlin Unit and coroutine body

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Assume there are some chained suspend functions like this.

```
suspend fun getData(): Boolean {
    return request().also {
        delay(1000)
    }
}

suspend fun request(): Boolean {
    return call()
}

suspend fun call(): Boolean {
    return run {
        delay(1000)
        true
    }
}
```

The above works allright. But if we convert the `also` block into a `Unit` param we will get an error: `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body`

```
suspend fun getData(): Boolean {
    return request {
        delay(1000) //the error
    }
}

suspend fun request(action: (Boolean) -> Unit): Boolean {
    return call().also(action)
}
```

Why is it so and is it possible to make the Unit inherit the coroutine body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the lambda parameter `suspend`:

```
suspend fun request(action: suspend (Boolean) -> Unit): Boolean {
```

Now the lambda parameter has a *suspending* function type, but `also` doesn't take that, so you can't pass it in directly like `also(action)`, you need to change it to:

```
return call().also { action(it) }
```

See also: [how to pass suspend function as parameter to another function? Kotlin Coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55886676/how-to-pass-suspend-function-as-parameter-to-another-function-kotlin-coroutines)